# Debugging a Laravel function called in JavaScript with PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, laravel-4, phpstorm

I need some guidance regarding how could I debug the following Laravel function mapped in a JavaScript function which is called in an HTML page.

```js
 $('#upload-avatar').fileapi({
     url: '{{ route("user.avatar") }}',
     accept: 'image/*',
     data: { _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}" },
     imageSize: { minWidth: 100, minHeight: 100 },
     elements: {
        active: { show: '.js-upload', hide: '.js-browse' },
        preview: {
           el: '.js-preview',
           width: 96,
           height: 96
        },
        progress: '.js-progress'
     },
```

as You can see the **user.avatar** Laravel function is called when I try to upload an image, my issue is if I hit the button Upload PhpStorm doesn't  activate.

I have the `Start listening for php debug connections` ON 
is there some extra configuration needed to debug JavaScript code embedded in an html page?

Comment: "Start listening for php debug connections" -- this button has NOTHING to do with JavaScript debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I figured that there is an option to debug in javascript Run ->Edit Configurations ->  Javascript Debug.  but still i dont get the php storm activation when hitting the upload button

Comment: 1) Which browser you are using? 2) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/JavaScript+Debugging+in+PhpStorm

Comment: yes, Im using google chrome, and also had that plugin already installed, the breakpoints dont work maybe because im using blade templates.

Comment: I just need a way to start debugging when I hit that UPLOAD button and see how data is being passed to the laravel functiion :(

Comment: *" the breakpoints dont work maybe because im using blade templates."* -- quite likely to be the case. Place your JS code into separate .js file and debug it that way.

Comment: @LazyOne I will do that, so there isnt another way? and thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use Chrome, open web developer tools and navigate to Network tab there
then when you try to upload the file, you will see a new request appear in that network tab
if you have 'debug' : true set in app/config/app.php config file, you will see detailed error from Laravel

Here's an example:
[image: Go to network tab in Developer tools]
[image: Click on Preview tab on that request]